# In 'Shadow of the Colossus' what is Wander's sword made of?

Tags: shadow-of-the-colossus

In the video game **'Shadow of the Colossus'** the character you play, Wander, is trying to revive his lover. Once he brings her to the temple and places her body onto the altar, a demon says he can revive her if our hero kills 16 colossi.

To help him in his quest, he only has his horse Agro, a bow (with infinite arrows) and a magical sword (the Ancient Sword, not the Queen's Sword or the Sword of the Sun).

**What material is this sword made of?**

[image: picture of main character carrying a sword]

Comment: I'm not entirely convinced that there is an official answer to this. Even the official wiki for the Ancient Sword (as the main weapon is termed), doesn't mention anything aside from its magical properties. I'm several Google searches in, and don't see any 'word of god' on the matter, nor any mention of the words 'iron', 'steel', or any kind of material. I'm almost positive it's not mentioned in game, as the dialogue in general is very sparse. The model, at any rate, does appear to be a steel-like metal, but, that's up for interpretation.

Comment: welp if it has no answer I should get the tumble weed award in like a week so thank you for trying to answer it!

Comment: My Japanese is pretty poor, but there seems to be a wealth of info in the artbook; http://sotc.bplaced.net/?page=thumbsbig

Comment: Any joy in translating these? http://i.stack.imgur.com/WPQvO.png

Comment: @Valorum it just describes the sword's property of reflecting light anywhere, guide you to colossi and showing their weak points. No word on material, origin or other lore.

Comment: @melboiko - Dammit. Well, I'm out of clever ideas. I'll try twitting at the artist/s but I doubt I'll get anywhere given how notoriously closely guarded they are about the game's plotline

Comment: Out of curiosity, what is the importance of knowing this if it is not documented. Seems like the developers of that world didn't see it as important what it was made of. Unless you're writing a fan fiction or pitching a sequel with that sword in it, the goal to know its material seems somewhat irrelevant. After all, it's not like such insight will allow you to forge one for yourself.